# Oracle error:- LRM-00116: syntax error at 'control' following '='

Tags: oracle, batch-file, oracle10g, sql-loader

Oracle DB/Windows XP:- 
I am running an batch file  that calls an  “.ctl” file   which in turn calls an “.xls” file, both present in the same folder.
The idea is to load the data onto Oracle db present on an remote oracle server.(non local machine)

I am getting this error, no matter what I do.

> Oracle error:- LRM-00116: syntax error at 'control' following '='

The .bat file code is as below

```
    rem SET SQLLOGIN=remod/P3w1d0ry@wsd

    pause Ready to Load the remo.Temp_data Table

    sqlldr userid=%SQLLOGIN% control=TempData.ctl errors=100 

    pause

The .ctl file is as follows:-
LOAD DATA
INFILE "data.xls"
replace
into table remo.Temp_data
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
test_abbr "rtrim(:test_abbr)",
test_pk       "rtrim(:test_pk)",
test_sk       "rtrim(:test_sk)",
test_dt       "rtrim(:test_dt)",
test_email       "rtrim(:test_email)",
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've remarked out the the `SET` of `SQLLOGIN`. Also you might want to put a call in front of the sqlldr statement. You'll also need some data to load...

```
SET SQLLOGIN=remod/P3w1d0ry@wsd

pause Ready to Load the remo.Temp_data Table

call sqlldr userid=%SQLLOGIN% control=TempData.ctl data=mydata.csv errors=100
```

Comment: but  when the files load, 
most of the fields are '[empty string] ',

Comment: a couple of fields have silly data example:-## ²²²ÿ ,ûT5¦ïå«¿Lý

Comment: and the log file shows only 50 inserts where as the .xls file has over 1200 files

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to load an Excel binary file as plain text.

Comment: @vas, you can't load a .xls. You will need to convert it into a .csv / .txt file first. The ctl file you've posted won't work either The columns you're performing operations on need to be the same as the columns you're loading into. I'd suggest you read [this FAQ](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL*Loader_FAQ), which is quite good.

Comment: the FAQ link is throwing an error "There is currently no text in this page, you can search for this page title in other pages or edit this page."

Comment: the sequence in csv sheet and DB table does not match